# Cannot exclude a path from basic auth when using a front controller script

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a small PHP/Apache2 web application wherein I'd like to do two seemingly incompatible operations:

1. Route all requests through a single PHP script (a "front controller", if you will)
2. Secure everything except API calls with HTTP basic authentication

I can satisfy either requirement just fine in isolation, it's when I try to do both at once that I am blocked. For no good reason I'm trying to accomplish these requirements solely with Apache configuration.

Here are the requirements stated as an example. A `GET` request for this URL:

```
http://basic/api/listcars?max=10
```

should be sent through `front.php` without requiring basic auth. `front.php` will get `/api/listcars?max=10` and do whatever it needs to with that.

Here's what I think should work. In my `/etc/hosts` I added

```
127.0.0.1 basic
```

and I am using this Apache config:

```
<Location />
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Home Secure"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwords
  require valid-user
</Location>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName basic
  DocumentRoot /var/www/basic
  <Directory /var/www/basic>
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /front.php/$1 [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
  </Directory>
  <Location /api>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    Satisfy any
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>

# another extant vhost in the same Apache2 config/server, for completeness
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName dustbin
  ServerAlias *.dustbin
  DocumentRoot /var/www/dustbin
</VirtualHost>
```

But I still always get a `HTTP 401: Authorization Required` response. I can make it work by changing `<Location /api>` into

```
<Location ~ /api>
```

but this allows more than I want to past basic auth.

I also tried changing the `<Directory /var/www/basic>` section into `<Location />`, but this doesn't work either (and it results in some strange values for `PATH_TRANSLATED` being passed to the script).

I searched around and found many examples of selective exclusion of basic auth, but none that also incorporated a front controller.

I could certainly do something like handle basic auth in the front controller, but if I can have Apache do that instead I'll be able to keep all authentication logic out of my PHP code.

A friend suggested splitting this into two vhosts, which I know also works. This used to be two separate vhosts, actually.

`<Location />` is outside the vhost because I want all vhosts to require basic auth by default. The one exception I wish to make is for all URIs starting with /api on this particular vhost. I omitted other vhosts because they didn't seem relevant to my question.

I'm using Apache 2.2.22 / PHP 5.3.10 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `RewriteRule` that's modifying the path is in a `<Directory>` block (which was done in order to make `%{SCRIPT_FILENAME}` have the full file path), the `[PT]` flag is implied on the rule.  Because the `[PT]` flag applies, the URL of the new request is re-mapped against locations - and the `<Location /api>` section no longer applies to the request.

So, given that, there's a few options.

- Take your rewrite rules out of the `<Directory>` block.

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName basic
    DocumentRoot /var/www/basic
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond /var/www/basic%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
    RewriteCond /var/www/basic%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /front.php/$1 [QSA,L]
    <Location /api>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
      Satisfy any
    </Location>
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- Use that regex `<Location>` - it can be restricted to prevent unintended matches.

  ```
  <Location ~ "(^|^/front\.php)/api/[^/]*$">
  ```
- Use `FallbackResource` instead of `mod_rewrite`.

  ```
  FallbackResource /front.php
  ```

Comment: Doesn't work--all resources on this vhost require basic auth. `<Location />` is outside the vhost because I want all vhosts to require basic auth by default. The one exception I wish to make is for all URIs starting with `/api` on this particular vhost. Sorry, I omitted other vhosts because they didn't seem relevant to my question.

Comment: @AdamMonsen Well, yeah, that's definitely relevant.  Can you provide an example of what those other vhosts look like, as well as any other global config blocks that might have an impact on authorization (anything with `Order`, `Allow`, or `Deny`)?

Comment: There is no other global config (anything outside a vhost) mentioning `Order`, `Allow`, or `Deny`. Why are other vhost sections relevant? Are their access controls not isolated from one another?

Comment: @AdamMonsen I want to make sure I'm not going to recommend something for your global config block that's going to blow up your other vhosts.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Done.

Comment: @AdamMonsen Thanks for the patience on all the extra info - turns out all I needed was to remember about this rather obscure behavior of mod_rewrite.  See edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help! By the way, I just noticed [Apache 2.2 adds the `FallbackResource` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/remapping.html#fallback-resource) which makes the use of `mod_rewrite` unnecessary for this case. `FallbackResource front.php` does the right thing!

Comment: @AdamMonsen Good alternative!  I'll add that to my answer for any future searchers that run into this question.